# Applying a different formula every nth row

Tags: excel, vba, row, formula

So i have this sheet where i'd like to apply a formula every 7th row. But it can't be the same formula, it needs to "offset" the formula as well.

For example, for the first range the formula would be "=(C4+C5)-C3"; for the second range, "=(C11+C12) - C10"; and so on.

This is what i have so far:

```
    Sub ApplyFormula()

    ApplyCF Range("C6")
    ApplyCF Range("C13")
'and so on, every 7 rows
'is there any other way i can apply these ranges instead of typing them?
'with an offset formula or something like that.

End Sub

    Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range)


    rng.Formula = "=(C4+C5)-C3"
    'i'd like the macro to "offset" the formula,
    'so for the C13 Range it would be "=(C11+C12) - C10"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `ApplyCF` sub, you could do this:

```
Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range)
If rng.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub ' in case your range is more than one cell

Dim prevCell As Range, twoPrevCell As Range, threePreCell As Range
Set prevCell = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
Set twoPrevCell = rng.Offset(-2, 0)
Set threeprevcell = rng.Offset(-3, 0)

rng.Formula = "=(" & twoPrevCell & "+" & prevCell & ")-" & threeprevcell
End Sub
```

It could definitely be tweaked, for instance, do you *need* to see the formula in the Formula Bar? We can evaluate that math in VBA and just put the answer in.

Per your comment, try this for every 6th cell (it's the whole macro, no need to split them):

```
Sub test()
' I assume you want to run this for every 6th cell in column C, starting with C1

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' gets us our last row in column C with data

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

For i = 6 To lastRow Step 6 'have to start at row 4, since any other row less than that messes up the formula
    Cells(i, 3).Select      ' because you can't have row 3-3
    Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=(" & Cells(i - 2, 3).Address & "+" & Cells(i - 1, 3).Address & ")-" & Cells(i - 3, 3).Address
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! It worked perfectly. Is there any way to show the formula in the Formula Bar? Also, is there any way i could apply the ranges in my `Sub ApplyFormula` every nth row until there isn't more data in the sheet? Because the ranges it may vary from sheet to sheet.

Comment: @Serveira - Yeah, it can be tweaked to run every 6 cells. Which is more accurate statement: Column C has data in all cells, but you only want every 6th cell, **or** Column C has data in every 6th cell.  Also, does the formula not show in the formula bar for you (when you select cell C6, for example)?

Comment: @Serveira - actually, could you just post a sample table to your OP? That way we can see how it's all laid out.  Ah, and to your second point about adding the formula to the formula bar - just add `.Formula` after `twoPreCell`, etc in the `rng.Formula` line.

Comment: Column C has data in all cells and i want it every 6th cell.The formula shows as the results, for example: =(33+0)-1779, instead of the cell values: =(C4+C5)-C3

Comment: How can i post a sample table here?

Comment: @Serveira - see my edit. And you'd just copy/paste into your OP, using the `{}` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If the formula needs to be displayed. Edited. Code below will work!  you need to use the parmateter "address" to reference a cell. the parameters false or true are here to say if one needs the relative (Set to false) or absolute (set to true) referernce

```
Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range)

         rng.Formula = "=(" & rng.Offset(-2, 0).Address(False, False) & _
         "+" & rng.Offset(-1, 0).Address(False, False) & ")-" & rng.Offset(-3, 0).Address(False, False)

    End Sub
```